# How dynamically group by and compute aggregate sums/maximums data with LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

We have an API to work with data that comes from different sources (database, webservices, plain text,...) so  we store it in a List structure.
We have this code to select some columns of them and apply functions to obtain new data (as sum two columns,...)

```
Func<dynamic[], object>[] leftFunctions = new Func<dynamic[], object>[this.Columns.Count];
IEnumerable<dynamic[]> returnValue = null
j = 0;
foreach (JoinDataColumn dataColum in this.Columns.OrderBy(x => x.Index))
{
     //Obtenemos para cada columna la funcion
     leftFunctions[j++] = dataColum.getLeftFunction(LeftDataQuery);
}
returnValue = (await LeftDataQuery.ExecuteAsync(parameters))
    .Select(x => leftFunctions.Select(f => f.Invoke(x)).ToArray());
```

In the above code: LeftDataquery is a class to obtain the list with data executing this, and returning `List<object[]>`

```
await LeftDataQuery.ExecuteAsync(parameters)
```

LeftFuncions are formulas to create new data from source data, "lefdataquery[1]+lefdataquery[2]" or simply "lefdataquery[0]" to obtain the data of the first column.

In the JoinDataColumn class I have a description of each column of the result List: name, type, and the agregate function.

At the end, the user can select the columns to group by and the agregation formula to the others ones (sum,max,min,count distinct,...). So now I have the returnvalue with a subset of columns of the original source and a list of index with the columns to group by and a list of indexes with their agregation formula (for example the index 1 is a SUM and so on)

```
public enum DataColumnAggregation { NONE = 0, SUM = 1, MAX = 2, MIN = 3 }
```

Any idea on how to group by this data and get the SUM/MAX/MIN,..

Doing some test I've wrote this code, but the problem is that the Groupby doesn't work with an object array as parameter. Any idea to have GroupBy working with this aproach?¿

```
    public enum DataColumnAggregation { NONE = 0, SUM = 1, MAX = 2, MIN = 3 }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object[]> returnValue = new List<object[]> { new object[] { "C1", 1, 2 }, new object[] { "C2", 3, 4 }, new object[] { "C1", 1, 3 } };


        DataColumnAggregation[] config = new DataColumnAggregation[] { DataColumnAggregation.NONE, DataColumnAggregation.SUM, DataColumnAggregation.MAX };
        //TODO agregar por la columna 0 , sumar la columna 1 y maximo de la columna 2 de returnvalue

        var resultado2 = returnValue.GroupBy(x => getGroupByColumns(x,config)).Select(x=>agregar(x, config));

    }

    private static object[] agregar(IGrouping<string[], object[]> x, DataColumnAggregation[] config)
    {
        List<object> result = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < config.Length; i++)
        {
            if (config[i] == DataColumnAggregation.NONE)
            {
                result.Add(x.Select(xy => xy[i]).FirstOrDefault());
            }
            if (config[i] == DataColumnAggregation.SUM)
            {
                result.Add(x.Sum(xy => Convert.ToInt32(xy[i]))); 
            }
            if (config[i] == DataColumnAggregation.MAX)
            {
                result.Add(x.Max(xy => xy[i])); 
            }
            if (config[i] == DataColumnAggregation.MIN)
            {
                result.Add(x.Min(xy => xy[i])); 
            }
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }


    private static string[] getGroupByColumns(object[] x, DataColumnAggregation[] config)
    {
        List<string> group = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i< config.Length; i++)
        {
            if (config[i] == DataColumnAggregation.NONE) group.Add(x[i].ToString());
        }
        return group.ToArray();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you are missing a lot of detail. Where is the `List` you are querying? What does `getLeftFunction` return? What is `LeftDataQuery`? Where are the parameters for the gorup by columns and the aggregation formula? What do you mean by "a list of index"?

Comment: Edited. The list of index, is an array with the agreagtion formula of the corresponded index in the result list

Comment: Can you provide the C# data types for these lists?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are attempting to group by `string[]` (or better, `List<string>`), you need an `IEqualityComparer` to pass to `GroupBy` that compares the elements.

```
public class IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) =>
        Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x != null && y != null && (x.SequenceEqual(y)));

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> src) {
        // Will not throw an OverflowException
        //unchecked {
        //    return src.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(17, (a, b) => 23 * a + b);
        //}
        var hc = new HashCode();
        foreach (var v in src)
            hc.Add(v);
        return hc.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

A factory class named `Make` helps create the comparer:

```
public static class Make {
    public static IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> SequenceEqualityComparer<T>() => new IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T>();
    public static IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> SequenceEqualityComparer<T>(T _) => new IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T>();
}
```

Now you can call `GroupBy` with the sequence equality comparer:

```
var resultado2 = returnValue.GroupBy(x => getGroupByColumns(x,config), Make.SequenceEqualityComparer<string>()).Select(x=>agregar(x, config));
```

NOTE: This causes the group `Key` to be `IEnumerable<string>`. If you prefer `IList<string>`, just replace `IEnumerable` with `IList` in the equality comparer class and the factor class. Or add an additional `IList` version with appropriate name changes.

Comment: Seems it works, but where is the HashCode class?¿ Thanks

Comment: @koes It is part of .Net Core 2.1 and greater.  If you aren't using that, you can use the commented out code and remove the `HashCode` code.